# What methods are generated for Scala case classes?

Tags: scala, case-class

What methods are generated for Scala case classes?

I know that some methods are generated specifically for case classes:

- equals
- canEqual

What are the others?

Also, I see that I can call productArity() on any case class. How does this work? In other words, why the following code is valid?

```
case class CaseClass()

object CaseClass {
  val cc = new CaseClass()
  cc.productArity
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way what methods are generated for a specific class in Scala is to use the `javap` command.

Find the .class file that was compiled by `scalac` and then run the `javap -private` command on it from your respective command line tool. This will show you the constructors, fields, and all methods for a class.

You can do this for your case class to see what kinds of things are automagically supplied by Scala.

Case classes mixin the `Product` trait which provides the `productArity` method. For case classes the `productArity` method will return the count of the parameter list supplied in the class definition.

Comment: I ran javap on the code provided and I could see that it generated some methods. All of the product methods were implemented there. However, there was method productElements() that returned iterator of Objects that I didn't get where it came from. productElements is not in Product. Is this method declared anywhere?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the method signature?

Comment: public scala.collection.Iterator<java.lang.Object> productElements();

Comment: So using scalac -print from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31392619/5088644) answer, here's what I got:
`@deprecated("use productIterator instead", "2.8.0") def productElements(): Iterator = scala.Product$class.productElements(CaseClass.this);`

We can see that productElements is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Given **Test.scala** -

`case class Test()`

You can run `scalac Test.scala -print` to see exactly what's generated

```
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // Test.scala
package com {
  case class Test extends Object with Product with Serializable {
    <synthetic> def copy(): com.Test = new com.Test();
    override <synthetic> def productPrefix(): String = "Test";
    <synthetic> def productArity(): Int = 0;
    <synthetic> def productElement(x$1: Int): Object = {
      case <synthetic> val x1: Int = x$1;
      case4(){
        matchEnd3(throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(scala.Int.box(x$1).toString()))
      };
      matchEnd3(x: Object){
        x
      }
    };
    override <synthetic> def productIterator(): Iterator = runtime.this.ScalaRunTime.typedProductIterator(Test.this);
    <synthetic> def canEqual(x$1: Object): Boolean = x$1.$isInstanceOf[com.Test]();
    override <synthetic> def hashCode(): Int = ScalaRunTime.this._hashCode(Test.this);
    override <synthetic> def toString(): String = ScalaRunTime.this._toString(Test.this);
    override <synthetic> def equals(x$1: Object): Boolean = {
  case <synthetic> val x1: Object = x$1;
  case5(){
    if (x1.$isInstanceOf[com.Test]())
      matchEnd4(true)
    else
      case6()
  };
  case6(){
    matchEnd4(false)
  };
  matchEnd4(x: Boolean){
    x
  }
}.&&(x$1.$asInstanceOf[com.Test]().canEqual(Test.this));
    def <init>(): com.Test = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      scala.Product$class./*Product$class*/$init$(Test.this);
      ()
    }
  };
  <synthetic> object Test extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0 with Serializable {
    final override <synthetic> def toString(): String = "Test";
    case <synthetic> def apply(): com.Test = new com.Test();
    case <synthetic> def unapply(x$0: com.Test): Boolean = if (x$0.==(null))
      false
    else
      true;
    <synthetic> private def readResolve(): Object = com.this.Test;
    case <synthetic> <bridge> <artifact> def apply(): Object = Test.this.apply();
    def <init>(): com.Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer
What version of scalac did you use? It didn't generate productElements, which is deprecated since 2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

It's true that a case classe automatically define `equals` and `canEqual` methods but it's also define `getter` methods for the constructor arguments. There's also a `toString` method that you can call.

A case class is also an instance of `Product` and thus inherit these methods. This is why you call productArity.